# Ratio problem of a beverage

Tags: arithmetic

I'm given the following data on a problem:

A company wants to produce a beverage AZ which is a mixture of beverage A and Z.

Cost/liter of A = 3.00$

Cost/liter of Z = 2.00$

I'm asked to determine the quatities of A and Z required to make 600 liters of AZ at 2.75$ per liter.

How would I go about finding the exact ratio for the ammount required?

---

I've tried going with a 50% to 50% ratio but it gets me to 2.5$/liter. I can go trial by error on ratios until I get it right, but something tells me that there is a way to get the exact solution required. If someone could help me get the logic going that would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let A be the number of litres of A and Z the number of litres of Z. So, A + Z = 600 and 3A + 2Z = 600(2.75). So, solve the equations to find A and Z.

Comment: I can't understand very well your notation. 3A won't get me 3 times the number of A liters? How would I go about solving for A or Z when they are both "related"?

Comment: First let X be the number of litres you use of A and Y the number of litres you use of Z. Do you agree that we must have X + Y = 600?

Comment: Yes. So far I'm understanding. I think the price/liter is what is confusing me.

Comment: Next, if you use X litres of A and Y litres of Z, then the total cost must be 3X + 2Y right?

Comment: Yes. if I want 1 liter of A and Z that would be equal to 5  (from  3+2), but still it would give me 2 liters of AZ in the end.

Comment: Now, you agree that X + Y = 600 and 3X + 2Y = 600(2.75), right?

Comment: Yes, the left part I agree, what I don't understand now is the right part where you put 600 x 2.75. Are you using the same relation as you did for 3X for example but instead of "X" you put 600 and 2.75 respectivly?

Comment: The total cost to make 600 litres at 2.75 per litre is 600 x 2.75. You understand that, right?

Comment: Yep, I do. that gives me a value of 1650$ for the 600 right?

Comment: Right. Now if you use X litres of A and Y litres of Z, then the total cost is 3X + 2Y. And you want 3X + 2Y = 1650

Comment: Yep, but if I want to solve for X that would give me I think: $ X=\frac{1650-2Y}3$ no?
And solving for Y would give me $Y=\frac{1650-3X}2$ no? how can I be able to solve one without the other? I can only think of system in that case but that would complicate things a bit or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You forgot that X + Y = 600. So, Y = 600 - X. So, 3X + 2Y = 3X + 2(600-X) = 1650. So, 3X + 1200 - 2X = 1650. So, X = 450 and Y = 150

Comment: You lost me on  3X + 2Y = 3X + 2(600-X) = 1650. Did you replace Y with 600-X?

Comment: yes, i did. Ok, now?

Answer (score 1):

What percent of $A$ and what percent of $Z$ do you need to create something that costs $\$2.75\text{ per liter}$?

Let $x$ be the percentage of $A$ you use. The cost for $1$ liter would be:

$$x\times\$3.00+(1-x)\times\$2.00$$

Solve for $x$ that makes the cost $\$2.75$.

$$3x+2(1-x)=2.75\\3x+2-2x=2.75\\x=.75$$

$75\%$ of $A$ and $25\%$ of $Z$ gets you a drink that costs $\$2.75\text{ per liter}$.

Comment: What is the function of the $(1-x)$ in the equation? are you taking $x$ away from 1 liter of A?

Comment: If $x$ is the percent of $A$ you are using, then you are using $(100\%-x)\%$ of $Z$

Comment: Aw, I see, but how did you get from 3x+2−2x=2.75 to x=.75? I think you skipped a step or two.